# Minecraft datapack wget

Tags: server, minecraft

I am running a 1.13 Minecraft server on Ubuntu Server 18.04, and I have no idea how to get a datapack with wget or something else. How do I do that? The normal download link is https://www.planetminecraft.com/mod/treecapitator-datapack-1-13/download/file/12032570/. Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Is your question how to use wget or which url to use? Going to the website you mentioned and viewing source, the current version of that datapack has a url of "https://static.planetminecraft.com/files/resource_media/mod/1909/treecapitator-v2-5-1-1551454023.zip" So typing `wget url-of-website` would successfully download.

Comment: I guess it is which url to use or how to use the one I have from command line.

Comment: Oh! I didn't read the whole comment, thanks for the link! How should I look for the link in the future?

Comment: I bet there's an automated way to do this, but unsure how. For me I followed your link then alt clicked on the blue download button and selected "copy link address"